# I want to free up storage on my mac in order to upgrade it to Monterey

Tags: mac, memory, upgrade

I have a question about how to free up mac's storage to upgrade to Monterey. My mac only has 128 GBS and the System takes up about 80 GBS. I bought a 128 GB memory card today because I thought it would help to add more storage to my mac to upgrade.

First, I deleted caches, all files, and applications I don't need on my Mac. I did all I can do, but available storage has remained the same. I don't know why, but iCloud showed up all of a sudden which hadn't existed until I started organizing files. I have 2 TB in iCloud. My Mac fan is working loudly and Mac's performance is so slow.

I have not still known how to use the flash memory card properly in terms of upgrading my mac. I know I can drag files into it, but I don't have tons of files and folders taking up too much storage of my mac.

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://www.derlien.com/index.html

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space